# Как сделать кнопки для приватных войс чатов?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Не понимаю, как должен выглядить await interaction.response, чтобы менять лимит участников в войсе, закрыть канал, или же открыть его, и, чтобы по нажатию открывалось меню для изменения названия канала

Comment: Это не вопрос, а задание или просьба. Называйте как хотите. Для получения ответа предоставьте уже имеющийся код, код ошибки или конкретно распишите то, что у Вас не получается. Код писать за Вас никто не собирается.

Comment: мне нужны примеры interaction, мне не нужны готовые кнопки, нигде не могу найти инфу, как это делать

Answer (score 0):

По вашей просьбе из комментария. Расскажу кратко, базовое.

Для отправки сообщения используется `interaction.response`:

```
@app_commands.command(name="ping")
async def test(self, interaction: discord.Interaction)
    await interaction.response.send_message(content="Пинг бота - ...")
```

Чтобы отправить сообщение видное только для одного пользователя, используйте `ephemeral`:

```
@app_commands.command(name="ping")
async def test(self, interaction: discord.Interaction)
    await interaction.response.send_message(content="Пинг бота - ...", ephemeral = True)
```

> `ephemeral = True` - сообщение видно только пользователю вызвавшему команду.

> `ephemeral = False` - сообщение видно всем пользователям.

Чтобы прикрепить кнопки к сообщению, используйте `view`:

```
class Buttons(discord.ui.View):
    ...

@app_commands.command(name="ping")
async def test(self, interaction: discord.Interaction)
    await interaction.response.send_message(content="Пинг бота - ...", view=Buttons())
```

А подробнее Вы можете узнать всё в [документации](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#interaction).